# Return Multiple List Values in Loop

Tags: python, list, csv, for-loop

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import csv
    
my_list = ['a', 'b','c','d']
    
def listIterations(inputcsv):
    for i in inputcsv:
        x = str(i)
        return x

print(listIterations(my_list))
```

Here's the output: `a`

Here is the desired output:

```
a
b
c
d
```

What I would like is for it to iterate through the list and output each element separately.

Ultimately I'll be using this function to feed a list into another function.

Comment: Anything wrong with putting the print statement in the for loop?

Comment: You're calling `return` at the end of the first iteration. If all you are doing is printing to stdout, I would call `print(x)` instead of `return x`, and then just call `listIterations(my_list)` instead of printing the return value.

Comment: `return` causes the function to exit immediately.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

Comment: You could have `listIterations` collect the values in a list, then return the list at the end.

Comment: Using 'print' instead of 'return' did it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `return` with `yield` to turn your function into a generator function. When you call it, it returns a generator object that you can iterate over at your leisure to produce the results you want one at a time:

```
def listIterations(inputcsv):
    for i in inputcsv:
        yield str(i)
```

```
>>> listIterations(my_list)
<generator object listIterations at 0x00000237062CC350>
```

You will only be able to use this object once. Since your input is a list, you can always call `listIterations` multiple times to get a new generator. To print, do a star-expand of the generator:

```
print(*listIterations(my_list), sep='\n')
```

Expanding the generator into an argument list will run it, and pass each element in to `print`. If you want to have a permanent record of the generated values, expand them into a list:

```
generated_values = list(listIterations(my_list))
```

or a tuple:

```
generated_values = tuple(*listIterations(my_list))
```

You can print the stashed values the same way:

```
print(*generated_values, sep='\n')
```

All that being said, if you just need an iterator over a list, you can obtain one using the builtin `iter`:

```
iter(my_list)
```

This is equivalent (for a list) to:

```
def listIterations(somelist):
    yield from somelist
listIterations(my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

In general what you are talking about is called [Generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). Using a generator you could achieve that with this piece of code:

```py
def listIterations(inputcsv):
    for i in inputcsv:
        yield str(i)
```

Or even shorter:

```py
def listIterations(inputcsv):
    yield from inputcsv
```

For more detailed answer see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do)

However in the specific case you described that can also be achieved with functional constructs.

```py
map(lambda x: print(x), my_list)
```

Normally map is used to replace the values in one iterable with some other value calculated based on the input value, but in case you simply map all the value to `None` and as a side effect print them. Note however that this is considered a bad practice to cause side effects in functional operators like map, it pretty much contradicts the basic concepts of functional programming (thanks for @C.Nivs for pointing this out).

Comment: I'd argue that using `print` inside a `map` (or `lambda`, for that matter) runs afoul of using functional style for side effects which may be better suited for an imperative style loop

Comment: @C.Nivs I definitely agree, this is not functional in style. It was just for the sake of showing another option for iterating an iterable.

Comment: You were doing great until the `map(print, ...` part. If you're going to do that, at least don't do `lambda x: print(x)` when you can just do `map(print, ...)`. Why not just `print(*listIterator(...), sep='\n')`?

Answer (score -1):

Remember that `return x` means "end the function, and pass on the value 'x'" so the line `return x` ends your function on the loop's first iteration, and passes on whatever 'x' is. That's why you just get `a`, the first item in your list.